# Running prepared statments inside for each loops

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am working with the following prepared statement inside a foreach loops. I have heard its bad practice to run queries inside loops. But this is the best way I can think of running a query.

Do you guys have any suggestions that can help me?  Below is my code. Thanks in advance

```
   $menu_items_and_prices = isset($_POST['items_and_prices']) ? $_POST['items_and_prices'] : NULL;

foreach($items_and_prices as $id => $item_and_price){
    $item = $item_and_price[0];
    $price = $item_and_price[1];

    $query = "UPDATE items SET item_name = ? , item_price = ? WHERE id = ? ";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bind_param("sii",$item, $price,$id);
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prepare the query just once - before the loop - and then execute it with different sets of parameters. Except from protecting against SQL injections, this is the main design goal of prepared statements.

Like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE items SET item_name = ? , item_price = ? WHERE id = ? ";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);

foreach($items_and_prices as $id => $item_and_price){
    $item = $item_and_price[0];
    $price = $item_and_price[1];
    $stmt->bind_param("sii", $item, $price, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Following the comments of @cdhowie you might add 
    // the following line:
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

Comment: I would add `$stmt->closeCursor();` at the very end of the loop.  Some drivers will throw a fit if you don't do this.

Comment: @cdhowie  I have a mySQL database... do I still need to add that?

Comment: @cdhowie IMO this makes only sense if there are still unfetched rows in the result but an UPDATE statement won't return any rows.

Comment: @hek2mgl That would make sense but this is not guaranteed behavior for all drivers, hence I always include it to maximize portability to different database engines.  If the driver doesn't require it then it's an inexpensive no-op.

Comment: @cdhowie It's hard to disprove what you are saying, just having that I didn't experienced such a problem before (with an UPDATE statement). Added that line, and pointing to your comment. Thx for your feedback!